# Unity and Eager Singleton

Tags: c#, singleton, unity-container

Good morning,
    I would like to have an eager singleton in Unity, this singleton needs to be injected into so the `RegisterInstance` methods alone would not do it. The only other thing I can think of is in the configuration module have something like:

```
container.RegisterType<Singletion, Singletion>(new ContainerControlledLigetimeManager());
container.Resolve<Singletion>();
```

but that seams a little fudge-y to me.

Comment: if you were using Windsor or Autofac you could make it a Startable  component...

Comment: If I was going to throw it away I think I'd use IKVM & Guice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best suggestion would be to implement a custom `LifetimeManager` class.  I can't find any useful documentation on how to do this, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. I've looked into this and could not work out how, I think it not doable even then. I ended up creating a custom LifetimeManager (extending ContainerControlledLigetimeManager) and a helper class. The helper class looped through all the registered classes and resloved any with that lifetime manager.